# How to validate only one .ascx page in an .aspx page while other .ascx pages also registered in the same .aspx page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I have some RequiredFieldValidators in both Insert.ascx and Update.ascx. I'm trying to validate the insert page, but then the fields which are in update page also try to validate, showing the required field validation message.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.Master"
    CodeBehind="client.aspx.cs" Inherits="Saver._Default" %>

<%@ Register TagPrefix="ins" TagName="Viewcomments" Src="Insert.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="upd" TagName="brcmsninfo" Src="Update.ascx" %>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `ValidationGroup` for each of your UserControl. `ValidationGroup` will fire validation only for those controls with the same `ValidationGroup` value

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the `ValidationGroup` property on each of your validation controls. See [this example](http://www.w3schools.com/ASPNET/prop_webcontrol_imagebutton_validationgroup.asp)